# Hectic absolute values? (where $a=ix$ and $b=-ix$)

Tags: complex-numbers

Where $a=ix$ and $b=-ix$ then what is:
$$|a+b|^2$$

$$|b-a|^2$$

And then is this equality true?

$$|a+b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2$$
because it seems $a+b=0$!

Comment: Whatever makes you think $|a+b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a+b=0$   and  $b-a=-2ix$   so   $|a+b|=0$  and  $|b-a|=2|x|$
Since $|a+b|^2=0$  and  $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 2|x|^2$  you  have  not  this  équality  in  general.
The  general   formula  about  complexe numbers  is :
$$|a+b|^2=|a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2 {\mathcal R}e(\overline ab)$$